# Can i implement loopback in Linux using socketCAN without CAN HW interface?

Tags: c, linux, loopback, socketcan

I am new on socketCAN and wanted to use socketCAN lib in Linux but i don't have CAN hardware interface to my system so i thought to implement it using loopback as we do it in TCP/IP socket programming. but i am not sure whether I can implement socketCAN using loopback and without CAN interface in C, so please let me know how can i do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

You can start here: https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.1/interfaces/socketcan.html

It's using VIRTUAL SocketCAN and with Python.